# Currency Selector not reflecting changed currency in footer due to magento cache

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, currency

I have two currency selector in my magento store one in header and other in footer.

When magento cache `Blocks HTML output` is disabled then both currency selector reflecting correct currency on change currency using any of selector.

But when magento cache `Blocks HTML output` is enabled from admin then currency selector in header reflecting correct currency but footer currency selector not showing correct currency on change currency.

How to resolve this with enabled magento cache?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am facing the same issue currently

Comment: Not yet, still my store's `Blocks HTML output` cache is disabled due to this conflict.